# No Wi-Fi adapter found in Ubuntu 18.04 dual-booted with Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, 18.04, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows 7. My Wi-Fi is working fine on Windows, but in Ubuntu it is showing `no adapter found`. I tried different methods (searching the last 7 days on Google). I also checked software update and everything is up to date, and yes, Ethernet is working fine in Ubuntu 
 - only Wi-Fi is not working.

Laptop model: Dell Inspiron 3542.

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
    libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

After trying things according to [this page on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx), I'm getting this error:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
```

Comment: would you have happened to modify your ```iwlwifi.conf``` file by copy pasting instructions from a blog post? Please try removing/replacing all the ```“``` characters in that file with a regular double quote

Comment: @AmithKK yes i tried but no effect always get errors

Comment: @AmithKK i get the error trying things again according to doc , i'm adding error in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I able to solve this issue here [ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542)

The commands usedto resolve my issue :

```
echo "blacklist dell-rbtn" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/dell-rbtn.conf
```

Comment: OK did you do anything else ? I have a E6540 that stubornly will not see anything wifi related